# How do I open a modal on top of another using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curently working on this piece of code, since i have a loader integrated in my site, the loader clashes with the modals, so i open the modal from my controller. my problem is if click open the modal it opens behind the current modal, whereas i want it displayed on top.

Comment: The solution is to apply this fix:

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `z-index` css property for the modal and/or the loader.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm! :)
But is there any other way without editing the css properties??

Comment: Where exactly did you change the z-index? I've spent all day trying to do that and couldnt achieve any result!

Comment: There is a default z-index on the modal backdrop and/or the loader. There is where you need to change/override on certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you should add `z-index` to your main modal popup div.

You can try [`ngBootbox`](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox). It's a library for popups.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm! :)
But is there any other way without editing the css properties??

Comment: You should show us your html/css. It depends on it but z-index is not a bad decision.